# JBoss SPNEGO Authentication Renewing Server Kerberos Tickets

Tags: kerberos, internet-explorer, jboss, single-sign-on, spnego

We have successfully configured SPNEGO with our webapp on JBoss EAP 6.2, Windows Server 2008, and IE10 using [JBoss Negotiation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/5/html-single/Negotiation_User_Guide/index.html).

What is best operational practice for renewing the ticket issued to JBoss to minimize Administrator intervention? The ticket can be renewed programmatically (before ticket endtime) with:

```
kinit -R
```

Though that can only be done up until the ticket's renew-til date is reached. Is it best practice to configure the ticket policy to set the renew-til field to something large (weeks,months)? Ultimately at some point after the renew-til time, an administrator will need to enter a password to assign JBoss a new ticket.

Is there better scheme to manage renewal of tickets for JBoss, or is manual administrator intervention at some point after the renew-til date (perhaps during a maintenance window) inevitable?